# How to implement a Stateful App Navigation using Rust and the Yew Crate?

Tags: model-view-controller, rust, frontend, lang, yew

I'm trying to build an app with navigation tabs and trying to use the best way to give state to the entire app. Currently the tabs are functional, but I am struggling to implement a way to both map and restore tab navigation via state in rust using the Yew frontent single page app framework. How do I link these tabs  and their respective context sections to state?

[Source files on github:](https://github.com/robust-systems/Rust_MVC)

My goal is to:

**Implement stateful tab navigation using Rust and the Yew crate.**

I've setup a toggle_tab function which uses the STDweb library to iterate over the existing HTML via class of `tabcontent`, `set attribute ("style", "display: none;")` . Then I match based on a unique class name (input via function and called from an `onclick` from exiting HTML) .

From the [Yew Examples on Github](https://github.com/yewstack/yew/blob/master/examples/todomvc/src/lib.rs), I know I may need to implement [storage](https://docs.rs/yew/0.8.0/yew/services/storage/struct.StorageService.html) into state and state into Model. What is a good way to implement app navigation with Yew & Rust?

HTML and Toggle Function:

```
impl Renderable<Model> for Model {
    fn view(&self) -> Html<Self> {
        html! {
    <>
        <nav class="tab grey lighten-2">
            <div class="nav-wrapper">
                // BUTTONS
                <ul class="row">
                    <div class="col s1" >
                    <button class="tablinks brand-logo welcome " onclick=|e| toggle_tab(e, ".welcome")>{"Welcome"}</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col s1 push-s1" >
                    <button class="tablinks brand-logo home active" onclick=|e| toggle_tab(e, ".home")>{"Home"}</button>
                    </div>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
        //SNIPPETS
        <div class="tabcontent white welcome content" >
                <Welcome/>
        </div>
        <div class="tabcontent white home content" style="display: block;">
//        <HomeTabs/>
        </div>
    </>
                        }
    }
}


fn toggle_tab(event: ClickEvent, tab_unique_class_name: &str) {
    use crate::stdweb::web::{IElement, IParentNode, INonElementParentNode};

    // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
    for tab in document().query_selector_all(".tabcontent").unwrap() {
        let tab: Element = tab.try_into().unwrap();
        tab.set_attribute("style", "display: none;").unwrap();
    }

    // Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "active"
    for tab in document().query_selector_all(".tablinks").unwrap() {
        let tab: Element = tab.try_into().unwrap();
        tab.class_list().remove("active");
    }

    let matching_tabs = document().query_selector_all(tab_unique_class_name).unwrap();

    match tab_unique_class_name {
        ".welcome" => {
            for elem in matching_tabs.iter() {
                let elem: Element = elem.try_into().unwrap();
                elem.class_list().add("active");
                elem.set_attribute("style", "display: block");
            }
        }
        ".home" => {
            for elem in matching_tabs.iter() {
                let elem: Element = elem.try_into().unwrap();
                elem.class_list().add("active");
                elem.set_attribute("style", "display: block");
                document().get_element_by_id("dashboard").unwrap().set_attribute("style", "display: block;");
            }
        }
        ".campaign" => {
            for elem in matching_tabs.iter() {
                let elem: Element = elem.try_into().unwrap();
                elem.class_list().add("active");
                elem.set_attribute("style", "display: block");
            }
        }
        ".comming_soon" => {
            for elem in matching_tabs.iter() {
                let elem: Element = elem.try_into().unwrap();
                elem.class_list().add("active");
                elem.set_attribute("style", "display: block");
            }
        }
        _ => alert("Catchall WHoahw!"),
    }
}
```

## Source code

If seeing more code helps, I uploaded the current source code here https://github.com/robust-systems/Rust_MVC/blob/master/src/components/tabs_level_1.rs

This is quite important and any guidance from you is very much appreciated.

[app appearance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZpZY.png)

[toggle tab function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmzKA.png)

[Html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNknw.png)

[Model, State, Msg, Filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gD4U4.png)

I realize that this is quite an abstract & verbose question so If any progress is made I will update it here.

Comment: The scope of this question is probably a bit too broad; is there a chance you can condense your code down a bit into a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), attempting to remove the bits of the code that, you know, work?

Answer (score 0):

## Answer from Yew Gitter;

@robust-systems (without looking at the other source code provided, just the code visible in the SO post) My suggestion would be to to emit a Message containing an enum representing which page you want tab you want to be selected instead of running toggle_tab. You can handle this Message in update and store the enum as part of your Model, indicating which is active.
From there, back in view, one way to utilize this state in the Model is to create small html snippets that you stitch together.
eg like:

```
let welcome_button = if let Tab::Welcome = self.active_tab {
    html!{
        <button class="tablinks brand-logo welcome active " onclick=self.link.callback(|_| Message::ChangeTab(Tab::Welcome))>{"Welcome"}</button>
    }
} else {
    html!{
        <button class="tablinks brand-logo welcome " onclick=self.link.callback(|_| Message::ChangeTab(Tab::Welcome))>{"Welcome"}</button>
    }
};
```

Then in your large html! block, you insert the `welcome button like

```
<ul class="row">
    <div class="col s1" >
    {welcome_button}
   ...
```

## Thoughts

How to now emit the msg and to where, i will hack up the [Custom-Components](https://github.com/yewstack/yew/tree/master/examples/custom_components) example on the yew github page. *will edit this answer once the application is fully stateful.

## Update

I finally got it fully stateful! Here is the resulting code for anyone who happens to find it useful.

I had to match a ChangeTab(Tab) Message and save the active_tab field in Model to Local Storage, then use an if let to restore the active_tab.

```
use crate::button_welcome::WelcomeButton;
use crate::button_home::HomeButton;
use crate::button_comming_soon::CommingSoon;
use crate::button_debug_panel::DebugButton;

use serde_derive::{Deserialize, Serialize};

use yew::prelude::*;
use yew::services::storage::{StorageService, Area};
use yew::format::Json;
use crate::tab_navigation::Tab::Home;
use std::sync::atomic::Ordering::AcqRel;

const RESTORE_KEY: &'static str = "tab_navigation";

pub struct TabNavigation {
    active_tab: Tab,
    storage: StorageService,
}

pub enum Msg {
    ChangeTab(Tab),
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub enum Tab {
    Welcome,
    Home,
    CommingSoon,
    Debug,
}

impl Default for Tab {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Tab::Home
    }
}

impl Component for TabNavigation {
    type Message = Msg;
    type Properties = ();

    fn create(props: Self::Properties, _: ComponentLink<Self>) -> Self {
        let storage = StorageService::new(Area::Local);
        let active_tab: Tab = {
            if let Json(Ok(active_tab)) = storage.restore(RESTORE_KEY) {
                active_tab
            } else {
                Tab::Home
            }
        };

        TabNavigation {
            storage: storage,
            active_tab: active_tab,
        }
    }

    fn update(&mut self, msg: Self::Message) -> ShouldRender {
        match msg {
            // active tab enum
            Msg::ChangeTab(tab_to_activate) => {
                match tab_to_activate {
                    Tab::Welcome => {
                        self.active_tab = Tab::Welcome
                    },
                    Tab::Home => {
                        self.active_tab = Tab::Home
                    },
                    Tab::CommingSoon => {
                        self.active_tab = Tab::CommingSoon
                    },
                    Tab::Debug => {
                        self.active_tab = Tab::Debug
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        self.storage.store(RESTORE_KEY, Json(&self.active_tab));
        true
    }

    fn change(&mut self, props: Self::Properties) -> ShouldRender {
//        if self.active_tab == Tab::Home
        true
    }
}

impl Renderable<TabNavigation> for TabNavigation {
    fn view(&self) -> Html<Self> {
        html! {
            // WELCOME
            let welcome_button = if let Tab::Welcome = self.active_tab {
                html! {
                    <WelcomeButton onsignal=self.link.callback(|_| Msg::ChangeTab(Tab::Welcome)) title="Welcome" class="active" />
                    // INSERT SECTION HERE
                }
            } else {
                html! {
                    <WelcomeButton onsignal=self.link.callback(|_| Msg::ChangeTab(Tab::Welcome)) title="Welcome" class="not-active" />
                }
            };
            // HOME
            let home_button = if let Tab::Home = self.active_tab {
                html! {
                    <HomeButton onsignal=self.link.callback(|_| Msg::ChangeTab(Tab::Home)) title="Home" class="active" />
                }
            } else {
                html! {
                    <HomeButton onsignal=self.link.callback(|_| Msg::ChangeTab(Tab::Home)) title="Home" class="not-active" />
                }
            };
            // COMMING SOON
            let comming_soon_button = if let Tab::CommingSoon = self.active_tab {
                html! {
                    <CommingSoon onsignal=self.link.callback(|_| Msg::ChangeTab(Tab::CommingSoon)) title="Comming Soon" class="active" />
                }
            } else {
                html! {
                    <CommingSoon onsignal=self.link.callback(|_| Msg::ChangeTab(Tab::CommingSoon)) title="Comming Soon" class="not-active" />
                }
            };
            // DEBUG
            let debug_button = if let Tab::Debug = self.active_tab {
                html! {
                    <DebugButton onsignal=self.link.callback(|_| Msg::ChangeTab(Tab::Debug)) title="Debug" class="active" />
                }
            } else {
                html! {
                    <DebugButton onsignal=self.link.callback(|_| Msg::ChangeTab(Tab::Debug)) title="Debug" class="not-active" />
                }
            };

            html! {
            <>
                {welcome_button}
                {home_button}
                {comming_soon_button}
                {debug_button}
            </>
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hi, i have this error: no method named `restore` found for enum `Result<StorageService, &str>` in the current scope
method not found in `Result<StorageService, &str>`